# How contact Name Is Populate

Tags: email

I have a custom object Quote__c I am sending an email from Quote, when i open the email Page Contact Name is not populating,I am selecting the contact manually, and quote also i am selecting manually is there is any way to populate all fields in that email page when button 
selection case..[image: Qpage]

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom link which will open the Send an email page in the current tab or new tab. Also, in the url to the Send an email page just append contact id and quote id to the query string and see if it populates in the email page.

You may want to take a look on how the URL is formed that is taking to the email page using a working model.

For example, this is typical URL from Account page.

https://na15.salesforce.com/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid=001i000000kEujW&retURL=%2F001i000000kEujW

and p3_lkid is the account id. In your case, you need to populate it in your url and make it as a custom link.

This gives you an idea of what you going to achieve.

Comment: i need to populate the contacts dynimaclly.

Comment: actually I have the send an email button in quote page, where quote is custom object, it have the relation ship contact.

Comment: i am tring below when ever some field in quote true at that time email page will open, but in that email page contact is not populating
if('{!Quote__c.Updated__c}' == 'true')
{
  window.location.href = '/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?id={!Quote__c.Id}' ; }

Comment: in that case, can you try to override the Send an email button and try to create a url that will take to send an email page with p3_lkid to contact id

Comment: email button is take and going to email page, but in that email page contact,quote are not populating i am choosing manually,

Comment: i replare my code like this   location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Quote__c.Id}}&p3_lkid={!Contact.Id}'); but contact is not poulating

Comment: i think your order of querystring parameters is incorrect. you need to follow the same pattern of what i have given above

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14214/discussion-between-sathya-and-baskaran-s)

Comment: any suggestions..for email button

Comment: Finally i got it:: we have to write in this manner    location.replace('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={!Quote__c.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Quote__c.Id}&p2_lkid={!Quote__c.ContactId__c}&template_id=00Xi0000000RUKO&new_template=1'); this is working code

Comment: Finally i say thanks For Supporting me.check my above working code.

Comment: wonderful @Sathya. Good to hear you nail down the issue. i am glad to help you!

Comment: i am going to vote for you. now you will get 500 reputation points